# How to dynamically (at a runtime) add menu items to NavigationDrawer in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, navigation-drawer, jetpack

I am building a Jetpack Compose 3 application. I have local database which holds information about "sensors". There could be no sensors defined in the database or n number of sensors. The user is able to create new sensors.

The SensorPage.kt displays details of each sensor. I would like the UI to display each sensor as a menu item (NavigationDrawerItem) in  a ModalNavigationDrawer.

The problem is each NavigationDrawerItem has to be hard coded and passed to ModalNavigationDrawer at the time of coding. Since these are dynamically loaded from database I have not been able to find a way how to accomplish this.

Any ideas and pointers into the right direction are appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Are you using Jetpack Compose drawer or the View one?

Comment: I'm using Jetpack Compose Material 3 ModalNavigationDrawer from   androidx.compose.material3   NavigationDrawerKt.class 
  Gradle: androidx.compose.material3:material3-android:1.2.0-alpha10@aar (classes.jar)

Comment: it would probably help others if you posted the code you have right now, just so everyone has the same starting point when trying to help

Comment: If you are using Compose drawer, you can just consume some `StateFlow<List<Sensor>>` from `ViewModel` and use a regular loop to create `NavigationDrawerItem`s. 
When the new Sensor is added, the `StateFlow` will emit a new value and the Drawer will recompose with the new list

Comment: Beauty! Thank you @lyrjie - it works like a charm!